# How can I design my Spring program so that when a user logs in I can tell if they are a Staff member, student or faculty member?

Tags: java, authentication, spring-security, database-design, authorization

A little more detail. Like I said I'm building this University Management System and it will have user authentication. It will also user authorization for some parts of the web layer, for example only a Student will be able to access the Student web portal to add/drop classes and only a Faculty will be able to use the faculty portal to grade students and see their list of course.

Here is the problem: When someone logs in (This is all using Spring Security and Spring MVC btw) I need to be able to tell if this a student, faculty or staff ideally from the login info itself. And querying each table until I find a match seems like TERRIBLE design. Each Entity inherits from a common abstract class Person but the interface that they share is very basic, they have getters and setters for the ID, first name, last name ect. I could store the Authorization role in the abstract class and that would tell me if this Person instance is a Staff, Student or Faculty and then check the role to figure what specific subclass I am using but that seems contrived as well. Is there a intuitive and common sense way to approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could create an enum field in the entity class called userType, and then create a filter class that determine the access to the functions located in the api layer, based on the userType of the user. You can get the userType efficiently by requesting it from the DB and store it in a data structure (like HashMap) on the server after the user logged in.